# Start Process not working with Impersonation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

I am having trouble invoking a batch file with impersonation (.NET 4.0)

I have a web application that invokes a test batch file residing on the local file system of the server. When I run it without impersonation it runs fine. But with impersonation the batch file doesnt produce any output, nor does it returns any error.

Here is the code for executing the batch file that i use -

```
public static bool ExecuteBatchFile(string fileLocationPath, string filePath, string arguments, TextBox textBox)
        {
            try
            {
                ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(filePath);
                procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                procStartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
                procStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = fileLocationPath;
                procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                procStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                procStartInfo.UserName = "XYZ";
                procStartInfo.Domain = "ABC";
                System.Security.SecureString pwd = new System.Security.SecureString();
                foreach (char c in "PWD")
                    pwd.AppendChar(c);
                procStartInfo.Password = pwd;
                procStartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;

                Process proc = new Process();
                proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
                proc.OutputDataReceived += delegate(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
                {
                    textBox.Text += "output rcvd\r\n";
                    textBox.Text += e.Data;
                };
                proc.ErrorDataReceived += delegate(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
                {
                    textBox.Text += "error rcvd\r\n";
                    textBox.Text += e.Data;
                };
                proc.Start();
                proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
                proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
                proc.WaitForExit();
                proc.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                textBox.Text += e.Message;
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Without impersonation i can see the output of the batch file. I get Output received with output of batch file and then an empty OutputReceived, and then an empty ErrorReceived.

But with impersonation, i can see nothing! Just one event for OutputReceived with no data, and one event for ErrorReceived with no data.

I have set impersonation in the web config file as follows:

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="ABC\XYZ" password="PWD"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar problem with Windows 2003 Server where my service hosted in IIS was executing application.

Things i discovered:
1. You must ajust permissions on service and configure it to output stack trace (including folder where .Net puts built service). 
2. Starting app with loading of user profile cannot be done from service. You can create wrapper application which you will execute without loading profile, and that app can in its turn execute app with loading of user profile. Wrapper must be built in Release mode and mustn't call Trace functions.
3. On service change you must 
- restart application pool in IIS snapp-in
- restart site
- execute iisreset.